# Why is webpack:// not appearing in chrome when using ng build

Tags: angular, webpack

Hi I'm kinda new to angular and I've found that when I use `ng serve` I see webpack:// in the chrome debugger so I can navigate my ts files to debug. When I use `ng build` webpack:// is not available. Is there a flag I can use or setting in angular.json to make the webpack:// visible when using `ng build`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that means somehow you're running in prod mode where you need to run in debug mode.  maybe try something like

```
--prod=false
```

when you build with prod=false, the transpiler knows to create .map files.  I think the .map files are the magic that allows the webpack mapping to work.  So now I'm thinking that you need to include the mapping files in your VS build html.

I know that the base html that VS creates is different from the base html that the Angular webserver uses.  So I would look at those 2 base files for differences.  The VS one is probably *.cshtml and the Angular one I think would be index.html.

You can also look at the dev tools when each of them is loaded and see if any other files are loaded up in the Angular version (probably the .map files)

Additionally you can try something like:

```
ng serve --source-map --vendor-source-map
```

Comment: after you do ng build how are you running it?

Comment: I'm running it from Visual Studio with an IIS server

Comment: I'm using serviceStack and I made a some changes in its configuration and it fixed it. I'm not exactly sure what it was that changed though that fixed it though. still figuring that part out

Comment: unknown option: '--vendor-source-map'

Answer (score 0):

In case if this helps someone else, I was banging my head against the wall for a while trying to figure out why breakpoints weren't being hit in Visual Studio for typescript files from an Angular project that I was running when I finally realized that it was because "sourceMap" was set to false in the angular.json file for the build that I was using. Setting it to true allowed the webpack to be visible in the browser which in turn allowed debugging in Visual Studio.